# How to stop flickity from jumping in mobile viewport

Tags: slider, flickity

I am using the Flickity slider (from Metafizzy) in a landing page to show different products. The slider is in portrait size and not landscape.

The issue is that when the user only scrolls the top portion of the slider into the viewport on mobile (i.e. 20-30%) and they attempt to scroll/swipe the slide, the screen suddenly jumps to attempt to include the whole slider into the viewport.

This never happens on the mobile emulator on the desktop, but only on the smartphone device on safari and google chrome browsers

**Is this intended to be a specific behaviour for the Flickity slider? Like I should not be using it to make portrait sliders?** I've gone through the plugin options and not able to fix this behaviour. It never came up in early testing with dummy content.

I've provided a link to the github page where it is happening, you can open it up in mobile browser and see the viewport "jumping" bug when you attempt to scroll the table. https://true-digital-channel.github.io/Galaxy11-Preorder/build/mobile.html

Answer (score 1):

Disable the keyboard accessibility by setting `accessibility: false` in the carousel options. From the Flickity [issue tracker](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/76).